# How to adjust the brightness of an LCD monitor using Compaq CQ62-win7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

My display hotkeys are not working; I can't adjust the brightness of my monitor, but the sound keys are working. However, I can't see the apps.

How can I adjust the brightness of my monitor without hotkeys?

Comment: Have you installed all the latest drivers for this computer?

Answer (score 1):

If Windows 7 believes that it can control the brightness of the screen, you can find the control under **Hardware & Sound > Power Options**.  At the very bottom of the window will be a brightness slider.

[image: This is a screen capture of the control panel window in question.]

You can also find your way there by going to **Appearance & Personalization > Display** and clicking the **Adjust brightness** link on the left.

These controls and links might not appear if Windows doesn't think it can control the brightness of the display.